# SetWindowsHookEx returns 0, GetLastWin32Error() returns 0 too

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I'm facing the problem, that my I'm unable to get a valid hookID returned by SetWindowsHookEx and that GetLastWin32Error() returning 0 too. I wrote the code below:

```
_LowLevelhookID = SetWindowsHookEx((int)HookType.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardHookHandler, IntPtr.Zero, GetCurrentThreadId());

int errorCode = -1;

if(_LowLevelhookID == (IntPtr)0)
{
    errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); 
}
```

Actually I want to create a low level keyboard hook for my application only and according to SetWindowsHookEx parameters description i shall set the hMod  parameter to null if I want to set the current threadID and capture only the keyevents for my application.

can anybody confirm that GetCurrentThreadId() is the correct method to desire the ThreadID in which my app is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook is global, you cannot install it for your app only.

`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` is not working  probably because you did not added `SetLastError = true` to `DllImportAttribute` for `SetWindowsHookEx`.

Comment: actually i did set SetLastError, i missed it in a first step, but corrected it afterwards. Ok, so in general WH_KEYBOARD_LL can not be used to cover key messages for my app only?

Comment: Well, you can always filter keyboard event manually in your hook proc checking if your app is active or not. Also look at `Remarks` section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - it defines hook scopes.